# In which elements is the selected element?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an array. The elements in the array represent the menu elements. I want to create "breadcrumb" according to the menu item I selected. However, it provides errors dynamically after 3 depth while working.

```js
// My Array

const menuArray = [{
    "label": "Dashboard"
  },
  {
    "label": "Products",
    "items": [{
        "label": "All Products"
      },
      {
        "label": "New Product"
      },
      {
        "label": "Product Categories"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "label": "Posts",
    "items": [{
        "label": "All Posts"
      },
      {
        "label": "New Post"
      },
      {
        "label": "Post Categories"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "label": "Sliders"
  },
  {
    "label": "Settings",
    "items": [{
        "label": "General Settings"
      },
      {
        "label": "User",
        "items": [{
            "label": "Your Profile"
          },
          {
            "label": "Edit Profile"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "label": "Social Settings"
      },
      {
        "label": "Link Settings"
      }
    ]
  }
];

// The function I experiment with
writeParent(event, arr) {

  let ct = 0;
  let found = false;
  let parentsLine = [];

  arr.some((e) => {
    parentsLine = [];
    let curr = e;
    for (curr; curr.items != null; curr = curr.items[0]) {
      if (event.label == curr.label) {
        found = true;
        return true;
      }
      parentsLine.push(curr.label);

    }

    if (event.label == curr.label) {
      found = true;
      return true;
    }


  });
  if (found) {
    return parentsLine;
  } else {
    return 'ERR: elm not found';
  }
}


console.log(writeParent({
  "label": "Edit Profile"
}, menuArray));
```

For example, if the element I selected is;

```
{
  "label": "New Post"
}
```

I want to get;

```
[
  {
    "label": "Posts"
  },
  {
    "label": "New Post"
  }
]
```

or

if the element I selected is;

```
{
  "label": "Edit Profile"
}
```

I want to get;

```
[
  {
    "label": "Settings"
  },
  {
    "label": "User"
  },
  {
    "label": "Edit Profile"
  }
]
```

I didn't know how to find the parent of the selected element. How can I do that?

Comment: So where is the code?

Comment: You must be use reduce function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: @epascarello Excuse me, I forgot. I just added it.

Comment: `some` is meant to return whether any of the elements in the array cause the given method to return true. Since you're not using the result, it would appear as though you're not using `some` as it is meant to be used, which is generally a bad idea. Use `forEach` if you just want to iterate, or `map` if you want to create a new array, or `reduce` to aggregate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem.

```js
menuArray = [{
    "label": "Dashboard"
  },
  {
    "label": "Products",
    "items": [{
        "label": "All Products"
      },
      {
        "label": "New Product"
      },
      {
        "label": "Product Categories"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "label": "Posts",
    "items": [{
        "label": "All Posts"
      },
      {
        "label": "New Post"
      },
      {
        "label": "Post Categories"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "label": "Sliders"
  },
  {
    "label": "Settings",
    "items": [{
        "label": "General Settings"
      },
      {
        "label": "User",
        "items": [{
            "label": "Your Profile"
          },
          {
            "label": "Edit Profile"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "label": "Social Settings"
      },
      {
        "label": "Link Settings"
      }
    ]
  }
];

function find(array, event) {
    if (typeof array != 'undefined') {
      for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i].label == event.label) return [event.label];
        let a = this.find(array[i].items, event);
        if (a != null) {
          a.unshift(array[i].label);
          return a;
        }
      }
    }
    return null;
}

console.log(find(menuArray, { "label": "Edit Profile" }));
```